# Как из базы данных FireBird (.fbd) в приложении под android получить данные?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, firebird

Есть приложение, которое использует базу данных `firebird`. Мне необходимо из этой базы вытаскивать несколько таблиц. На данный момент пишу приложение под "андроид", данное приложение должно при первом запуске скачивать или обновлять свою базу данных из базы данных `firebird`.

Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/devel-jdbc-driver/

Comment: https://github.com/yakreved/FirebirdAndroidClient/tree/master/app/src/main/java - Вот это похоже на то, что вам нужно

Comment: Буду пробовать , спасибо за ответ.